# What is the proper formula to calculate these percentages?

Tags: excel, math, percentage

Here is the formula I'm using:

```
=B4/SUM(B4,C4)
```

Here are my results.  As you can see, everything is fine except row L, which should have a negative percentage.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> everything is fine except row L, which should have a negative percentage.

Why?  `3010/(3010+5075) = 3010/8085 = 37.23%`

If you're trying to calculate percentage *growth* then the right formula is:

```
=(B4-C4)/C4
```

You need to decide what to use if `C4` is 0 (otherwise you'll get a `#DIV/0!` error).

Comment: Crap.  Sometimes I think I had a stroke and nobody ever told me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the opposite of growth (shrinkage?) then you could get that with this formula

`=1-C4/B4`

That would give you similar results to now (the 100% values would all be 100% but some would change slightly, e.g. row F would be 80%).....and row L will be a negative value because instead of shrinkage you get growth......